# Are there any resources for cool silverlight image animations?

Tags: silverlight, flash, animation

I found [Vectorlight](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/tutorials.aspx) which is quite good, but are there any tutorials or 
books about doing cool effects with silverlight. I'm after for resources focused more 
for a designing and presentation. Mostly the books about Silverlight is focused on doing 
boring business applications like making grids and forms. Why aren't there any great resources for designing with Silverlight. Flash has tons!

Comment: It might help if you define what you mean by an "effect"?

Comment: I mean animations. Everybody loves animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find some more creative content for Silverlight take a look at the [Expression Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/).

If by image effects you mean pixel shading then take a look at the [Shazzam tool](http://shazzam-tool.com/default.html)